# Issues installing packages in R: "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed"

Tags: r

I'm trying to install tidyverse and tidycensus, among other packages, and I'm getting a similar error for all of them. I'm working on a Mac. I've tried installing the dependencies separately, but I get similar error. I've tried installing RTools, but that didn't change anything. I wish I could give more information, but I've never encountered an error like this.

Here's the code:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

And here's the output:

```
    also installing the dependency ‘broom’


  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
broom  0.5.6  0.7.0             FALSE

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/tidyverse_1.3.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 432989 bytes (422 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 422 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/6k/0tw5jym93c762cchf9bym93w0000gn/T//RtmpNdVhZw/downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘broom’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/broom_0.7.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 604195 bytes (590 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 590 KB

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/INSTALL: line 34: 20265 Done                    echo 'tools:::.install_packages()'
     20266 Abort trap: 6           | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES= LC_COLLATE=C "${R_HOME}/bin/R" $myArgs --no-echo --args ${args}
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/6k/0tw5jym93c762cchf9bym93w0000gn/T/RtmpNdVhZw/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: What version of macOS are you running? I thought RTools was only for windows, did you mean clang? When it asked you, did you choose to built from source or install pre-built binaries? Have you restarted R before each attempt? Do you have multiple copies of R running at the same time?

Comment: @MrFlick I'm running Sierra 10.12.3. I meant clang. It never actually stopped running and asked if I wanted to build from source or binary. I did restart R. I've also uninstalled R and Rstudio and reinstalled. I don't have multiple copies of R running at the same time.

Comment: It looks like you're running R version 4.0 but that requires "macOS 10.13 (High Sierra) and higher" (per the download page). You'll probably need to upload your OS or download an older version of R (though not all packages might support older versions of R)

Comment: @MrFlick Downloading an earlier version of R worked. Thank you!